# ORACLE: Can I get results of "SHOW PARAMETER" into a variable or table?

Tags: oracle

When I execute `SHOW PARAMETER CONTROL_MANAGEMENT_PACK_ACCESS`, it gives me the value of this Oracle parameter as part of what appears to be a single row with three columns (name, type, and value). How can I get this value into a variable or table that I can use later in my script?

I'm trying to make a decision later in my script based on a few parameter values and I'm not sure how to store them in something persistent.

Comment: Can you query `v$parameter` instead?  `show parameter` is just SQL*Plus syntactic sugar for a query against that.

Comment: @JustinCave Hmm, I sure can - I didn't realize those were synonymous (betraying my primary focus of MSSQL, not Oracle). If this were an answer, I'd accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query [`v$parameter`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/dynviews_2085.htm) instead (or [`v$system_parameter`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10755/dynviews_2132.htm) in the event that you've changed session-level parameters in your current session and want to ignore those changes).  `show parameter` is just SQL*Plus syntactic sugar on top of those data dictionary views.

Comment: I didn't realize this was a syntax issue - thanks for pointing me to the correct system view!